# TeckNet mechanical keyboard lights not controllable

Tags: keyboard, brightness

I've got a TeckNet mechanical keyboard with LED backlights, when I had the keyboard plugged into Windows, I was able to hold the function key down and turn the lights off, on, rotating etc. Also change the brightness.

I've plugged it into Ubuntu 21.04 and none of these features seem to work. The keyboard seems to be stuck on the rotating light scheme.

Does anyone know any way of managing the lighting on this keyboard?

https://smile.amazon.co.uk/TeckNet-Mechanical-Anti-ghosting-Waterproof-Aluminium/dp/B005TIYDJC/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=tecknet+keyboard&qid=1630924317&sr=8-5

Comment: Does it come with a driver for Ubuntu? If not most likely you can  not control this feature.

Comment: It didn't come with a driver for Windows either.

Comment: With no driver for Ubuntu it is likely the features wont work.